# Not able to set state in componentWillReceiveProps in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the state of a component with new props received by the parent component.

However, the setState call doesn't seem to be working as I would expect.

I understand componentWillReceiveProps won't re-render the component, but it doesn't even seem to be allowing a setState call.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

The code:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  this.setState({name: nextProps.site.name});
  console.log(nextProps.site.name); // logs the updated name
  console.log(this.state.name); // logs the old name, even after presumably being set again
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done asynchronously. So you may not  see the update within the method. Check that in componentDidUpdate.

Comment: Thanks, goldbullet! I've been working with React now for a while, and I still find the lifecycle of the components a bit baffling sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

you can see the result in the `setState` callback , like this :

```
this.setState({name: nextProps.site.name} , ()=>{

console.log(this.state.name);

});
```

Comment: This is a great tip! Thanks, Alireza!