# setState() wiith Redux in React

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am learning Redux with React. I am using `dispatch` like below

```
this.props.dispatch(uploadImage(formData, config, element_id));
```

My `mapStateToProps` is like below

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    uploadImage: state.addressReducer.uploadImage
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ModalElement);
```

I would like to get output like below

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.uploadImage) {
        this.setState({ photostatus: 'image' });
        console.log(this.state.photostatus)  // getting wrong output, not `image`
    }
}
```

Here is my Repo   https://github.com/afoysal/mern/blob/master/client/src/components/ModalElement.js

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (nextProps.uploadImage) {
    this.setState({ photostatus: 'image' 
  },()=>console.log(this.state.photostatus))
 }
```

check by changing this way

Comment: Thanks @Kishan Jaiswal for your solution. I know your solution. But my component needs `photostatus: 'image'` when I am calling it. setState Callback is not working here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171184/not-able-to-set-state-in-componentwillreceiveprops-in-react 
please read this and also about the llifecycle on componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps rendering is different from all other lifecycles

Comment: Thanks @Kishan Jaiswal for your solution. What should I do here ? What is your opinion in this situation ? Should I use `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentWillReceiveProps` ? Thanks.

Comment: My issue is in `this.setState()`. How can I set the state of  `photostatus` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.uploadImage) {
        this.setState({ photostatus: 'image' }, () =>{
          console.log(this.state.photostatus)  // this.setState is asynchronous so you won't find the changes immediately
        }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anita for your solution. I know your solution. But my component needs `photostatus: 'image'` when I am calling it. setState Callback is not working here.